# How to switch values and keys with python dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

My input is:

```
files = {
    'Input.txt': 'Randy',
    'Code.py': 'Stan',
    'Output.txt': 'Randy'
}
```

I want the output as:

```
{'Randy':['Input.txt','Output.txt'], 'Stan':['Code.py']}
```

Basicly it's the other direction of this [switch key and values in a dict of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422204/switch-key-and-values-in-a-dict-of-lists)

This is what I tried:

```
dictresult= {}
for key,value in files.items():
     dictresult[key]=value
     dictresult[value].append(key)
```

But it doesn't work. I get `KeyError: 'Randy'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [switching keys and values in a dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305518/switching-keys-and-values-in-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's simple approach where we iterate over `keys` and `values` of your original dict `files` and create list for each value to append to it all keys corresponding to that value.

```
files = {
    'Input.txt': 'Randy',
    'Code.py': 'Stan',
    'Output.txt': 'Randy'
}

dictresult= {}

for k, v in files.items():
    if v not in dictresult:
        dictresult[v] = [k]
    else:
        dictresult[v].append(k)

print(dictresult) # -> {'Randy': ['Output.txt', 'Input.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit? How it works without the usage of update method?

Comment: I'll pinpoint my question better, Why are uasking for v not in dict rather than v not in dict.keys()

Comment: That's the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems with your code.

Let's review:

- Firstly, you're getting key error because you're trying to append a value to key that doesn't exist. Why? because in you earlier statement you added a value to dict[key] and now you're trying to access/append dict[value].

  ```
  dictresult[key]=value
  ```
- You're assigning value to newly generated key, without any check. every new value will overwrite it.

  ```
  dictresult[value].append(key)
  ```
- Then you're trying to append a new value to a string using a wrong key.

You can achieve what you want by the following code:

```
d = {}
for key,value in files.items():
if value in d:
    d[value].append(key)
else:
    d[value] = [key]
print(d)
```

It will output:

```
{'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```

How/why it works?

Let's review:

- The if condition checks if that key is already present in the dictionary. When iterated over a dictionary, it returns it's keys only, not key value pairs unlike dict.items()
- If the key is there we simply append the current value to it.
- In other case, where that key is not present, we add a new key to dictionary but we do it by casting it to a list, otherwise a string would be inserted as a value, not a list and you won't be able to append to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) -

```
from collections import defaultdict
dictresult= defaultdict(list)
for key,value in files.items():
     dictresult[value].append(key)
```

This will assume there is an empty list in every item in the dictionary so the append won't fail

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value as a key exist in dictresult

Like

```
dictresult= {}
for key,value in files.items():
     if not value in dictresult: dictresult [value]=[]
     dictresult[value].append(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = {}
for key, value in files.items():
    output[value] = output.get(value, []) + [key]

print(output)
# {'Randy':['Input.txt','Output.txt'], 'Stan':['Code.py']}
```

Comment: @Luis check this also if its help

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways how you can do it.

```
from collections import defaultdict


files = {"Input.txt": "Randy", "Code.py": "Stan", "Output.txt": "Randy"}    
expected = {"Randy": ["Input.txt", "Output.txt"], "Stan": ["Code.py"]}


# 1st method. Using defaultdict
inverted_dict = defaultdict(list)
{inverted_dict[v].append(k) for k, v in files.items()}
assert inverted_dict == expected, "1st method"

# 2nd method. Using regular dict
inverted_dict = dict()
for key, value in files.items():
    inverted_dict.setdefault(value, list()).append(key)
assert inverted_dict == expected, "2nd method"

print("PASSED!!!")
```